# Need to run a batch file inside Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a workspace with multiple projects. All are Maven projects. The target directory of one of the projects contains a batch file after it is built. Now, I need one of the other projects in the workspace to run this batch file. So, I want to get the path to the current workspace programmatically without introducing new dependencies to accomplish this. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Edit 1:  I have a parent Maven project in the workspace.  One of its children's target directory contians the batch file.  A different child of the parent (which is a testing project) needs to run the batch file.  I can use the Maven basedir variable to get the batch file which isn't pretty and doesn't work if I am running individual tests with Eclipse.  So I'd like to avoid that solution.

Comment: maybe not helpful, but my advice: burninate that batch file. stick to Maven/Ant.

Comment: Sorry. I meant remove, get rid of. If you use Maven/Ant, you can stay cross platform and declarative in nature. Batch files are clunky.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you'll have is that projects in Eclipse aren't necessarily stored in the workspace directory; they could be anywhere on the file system. This means that simply knowing where the workspace is won't necessarily help you find the batch file.

For example: my workspace is `$HOME/workspace`, but all my projects (the working copies) are in `$HOME/code/project`. Being able to determine the workspace isn't very helpful. Projects can exist outside the workspace, and still appear in Eclipse by using *File -> Import*.

Your best bet is probably to 'attach' the batch file to the build using the [attach-artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal of build-helper-maven-plugin. There's an example of how to do that [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html#Attach_additional_artifacts_to_your_project).

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>script.bat</file>
              <type>bat</type>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then, your other project can use the [copy goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) of maven-dependency-plugin to resolve the script into its own directory and run it from there.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>...</groupId>
              <artifactId>...</artifactId>
              <version>...</version>
              <type>bat</type>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scripts</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions.  I'll let you know what approach I took.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)? It's not pretty, but it gets the job done:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions> 
        <execution> 
            <id><!-- insert an id --></id> 
            <phase><!-- insert a maven lifecycle phase --></phase> 
            <configuration> 
                <tasks> 
                    <exec 
                        dir="${basedir}" 
                        executable="${basedir}/src/main/sh/your-script.sh" 
                        failonerror="true"> 
                        <arg line="arg1 arg2 arg3" /> 
                    </exec> 
                </tasks> 
            </configuration> 
            <goals> 
                <goal>run</goal> 
            </goals> 
        </execution> 
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Perhaps edit to address this requirement: "I need one of the *other* projects in the workspace to run this batch file"?

Comment: Ok, so it gets a little messier, but what you could do is to include the project with the script as a dependency, use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to [unpack-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-project-dependencies.html), and then use the maven-antrun-plugin.